# Remove Pattern to first space occurrence with sed

Tags: sed

i need to remove my postfix log lines from this:

```
Jun 12 06:19:20 cm postfix: 123123: to=<xxxxx@xxx.xxx>, relay=x.x.x.x, conn_use=3, delay=2, delays=1.6/0/0.01/0.32, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as XXXXXXX)
```

to this:

```
Jun 12 06:19:20 cm postfix: 123123: to=<xxxxx@xxx.xxx>, relay=x.x.x.x, delay=2, delays=1.6/0/0.01/0.32, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as XXXXXXX)
```

i only need to remove "conn_use=3, ". This value may be variable (conn_use=12.5 for example)
I tried with:
sed 's/conn_use=.*\ //'
but it delete anything till the last (basically, after "as"): XXXXXXX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/conn_use=[^,]*, //' file
```

The output:

```
Jun 12 06:19:20 cm postfix: 123123: to=<xxxxx@xxx.xxx>, relay=x.x.x.x, delay=2, delays=1.6/0/0.01/0.32, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as XXXXXXX)
```

---

- `[^,]*` - matches any character except `,`

Answer (score 1):

voila:

```
sed 's/conn_use=[^,]*, //'<<< 'Jun 12 06:19:20 cm postfix: 123123: to=<xxxxx@xxx.xxx>, relay=x.x.x.x, conn_use=3, delay=2, delays=1.6/0/0.01/0.32, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as XXXXXXX)'
```

output:

```
Jun 12 06:19:20 cm postfix: 123123: to=<xxxxx@xxx.xxx>, relay=x.x.x.x, delay=2, delays=1.6/0/0.01/0.32, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as XXXXXXX)
```

Comment: :D I wasted some second to copy output after test on terminal :3 and yep, my respect to u (without pathetic) :3

Comment: that's ok, I hope you know what to do